# How to know which thread has lock preferably using Visual Studio debugger (.net programming)?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am just using simple lock to manage some shared data.

Is there a way to know which thread took the lock?

Basically someone already acquired lock and didn't release it. So, all the subsequent operations are simply struck at taking lock and timing out.

I am kind of stuck as from debugger it is simply stuck at lock as some one already acquired it and I looked at "Debugger + Windows+ Threads" after "Break All" - no thread entered lock.

It doesn't show any thread which entered the critical section.

There is probability that someone took lock and that thread has been aborted. But I am expecting lock to be released even though thread has been aborted. Is my expectation wrong?

---

Here is my class - basically its a powershell cmd runner and cmds can be executed from multiple threads:

```
internal abstract class PowerShellCommandRunner : IDisposable
{
    #region Fields
    protected object m_syncObject = new object();
    private PSSession m_psSession = null;
    private Runspace m_runspace = null;
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public PowerShellCommandRunner(ExchangeApplicationSystem system)
    {
        if (null == system)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ExchangeApplicationSystem");
        }
        this.ExchangeApplicationSystem = system;
        this.PSCredential = this.ExchangeApplicationSystem.Credential.GetPSCredential();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties


    internal ExchangeApplicationSystem ExchangeApplicationSystem
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public PSCredential PSCredential
    {
        get;
        protected set;
    }

    private bool IsNotInitializedOrInvalidRunspace(Runspace runspace)
    {
        bool flag = (null == runspace) //not initialized
            || (null == runspace.RunspaceStateInfo) //not state info (defensive)
            || (runspace.RunspaceStateInfo.State == RunspaceState.Broken) //runspace state is broken
            || (null != runspace.RunspaceStateInfo.Reason); //there is an exception
        return flag;
    }

    private bool NeedToCreatePsSession
    {
        get
        {
            bool flag = (null == this.m_psSession)
                || this.IsNotInitializedOrInvalidRunspace(this.m_psSession.Runspace);
            return flag;
        }
    }

    internal Runspace Runspace
    {
        get
        {
            lock (this.m_syncObject)
            {
                if (this.IsNotInitializedOrInvalidRunspace(this.m_runspace))
                {
                    if (null != this.m_runspace)
                    {
                        //already have one runspace - close it, before we create another one
                        this.CloseRunspace();
                    }
                    this.m_runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
                    this.m_runspace.Open();
                }
                return this.m_runspace;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods

    internal IEnumerable<PSObject> Execute(string cmd, params object[] argumentList)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmd))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cmd");
        }
        return this.Execute(new Command(cmd), argumentList);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sub-classes can do their own specific implementation to create ps-sessions
    /// The base class simply performs primitive oepratiosn like managing them.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    internal abstract PSSession GetPSSession();

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the pssession and if reuired updates it as well
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>        
    private PSSession GetAndUpdateManagePSSessionInfRequired()
    {
        //Note: we dont need to lock as the callers (Exceute methods) will be acquiring the lock before executing the code
        //but, just locking it again as the locks are re-entrant
        lock (this.m_syncObject)
        {
            if (this.NeedToCreatePsSession)
            {
                if (null != this.m_psSession
                    && (null != this.m_runspace))
                {
                    //if ps-session exists, remove it from runspace
                    this.RemovePsSessionFromRunspace();
                    //Yes, there can be a case where some one already have a reference to the remove session
                    //that's ok, as the operation simply throws
                    //And subsequently they will be releasing and re-using the new one.
                    this.m_psSession = null;
                }
                //now, open a new session (requesting for a new session from subclasses)
                this.m_psSession = this.GetPSSession();
                Debug.Assert(null != this.m_psSession);
            }
            return this.m_psSession;
        }
    }

    internal IEnumerable<PSObject> Execute(Command cmd, params object[] argumentList)
    {
        if (null == cmd)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cmd");
        }
        lock (this.m_syncObject)
        {
            //Pipelines cannot be executed concurrently, so serialize it                
            OperationProgressReporter.Report(string.Format("Executing the following PowerShell Command: {0}", cmd.ToString()));
            return this.Runspace.ExecuteCommand(cmd, this.GetAndUpdateManagePSSessionInfRequired(), argumentList);
        }
    }

    internal IEnumerable<PSObject> Execute(ScriptBlock sb, params object[] argumentList)
    {
        if (null == sb)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("scriptblock");
        }
        lock (this.m_syncObject)
        {
            //Pipelines cannot be executed concurrently, so serialize it                
            OperationProgressReporter.Report(string.Format("Executing the following PowerShell Command: {0}", sb.ToString()));
            return this.Runspace.ExecuteCommand(sb, this.GetAndUpdateManagePSSessionInfRequired(), argumentList);
        }
    }

    private void RemovePsSessionFromRunspace()
    {
        //not intended to call before acquiring a lock 
        //(For ex: either while closing runspace or while getting rid of old session and getting a new one (GetAndUpdateManagePSSessionInfRequired)
        //but locking it as the locks are re-entrant (defensive)
        lock (this.m_syncObject)
        {
            if ((null != this.m_psSession)
                && (null != this.m_runspace))
            {
                try
                {
                    string errorMsg = null;
                    this.m_runspace.RemovePsSessionFromRunspace(this.m_psSession, out errorMsg);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMsg))
                    {
                        FxTracing.TraceError(TraceEventId.GeneralError, errorMsg);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ExceptionManager.GeneralExceptionFilter(ex);
                    OperationProgressReporter.Report(OperationProgressMessageLevel.Verbose,
                        string.Format("<DEBUG> Unable to remove PSsession from runspace in '{0}'", this.ExchangeApplicationSystem));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void CloseRunspace()
    {
        //lcok it
        lock (this.m_syncObject)
        {
            //check again to make sure only one thread enters
            if (null != this.m_runspace)
            {
                try
                {
                    //if a ps-session is created, remove it
                    if (null != this.m_psSession)
                    {
                        //remove the pssession from runspace
                        this.RemovePsSessionFromRunspace();
                    }
                    //then close the runspace
                    this.m_runspace.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //swallow
                    ExceptionManager.GeneralExceptionFilter(ex);
                    Debug.Fail(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    //finally, set the runspace to null
                    //Yes, the runspace can be set to null while another thread can have a reference to old runspace
                    //its ok as the operation simply fail with invalid runspace state exception (most likely)
                    //And when they retry they get the updated runspace or get a new one.
                    //same appraoch as managing ps-session
                    this.m_runspace = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region IDisposable
    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.CloseRunspace();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: could you share the code ?

Comment: Please provide more information on your threadmodel and your lock. Code is prefered.

Comment: Your expectation that the lock will be released even if a thread holding it is aborted is reasonable. Any unexecuted `finally` blocks are executed before a thread is aborted (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx). Note that if a thread calling .Abort() holds onto a lock on any resource that the other thread's `finally` region requires, this may cause a deadlock.

Comment: You've obviously put a fair bit of thought into this code. One thing caught my eye though (and this is pure speculation): you are calling `OperationProgressReporter.Report` from a number of code regions protected by the lock. This will potentially execute some outside code. If that code happens to dispatch a synchronous message to another synchronization context, which in turn invokes one of the methods or property accessors on the same `PowerShellCommandRunner` instance (hitting the same lock), you've got yourself a deadlock.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this would help:

1. Enable unmanaged debugging (Project Properties > Debug > check "Enable unmanaged code debugging"
2. Set a breakpoint somewhere
3. When the execution breaks, in the Immediate window, type: `.load sos` and then type `!SyncBlk -a`

Answer (score 2):

Just add some diagnostic print messages using `Debug.WriteLine` to see whch thread has entered critical section.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is a quite old question... But I found that in VS 2022 the Parallel Stacks window will show this:

[image: Parallel Stacks window showing locking thread]

Very convenient. Thanks VS-Team!